# AutoMapper How to get nested object of nested object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I am trying to map values from Person class who is nested in User class. User class is nested in ResearcherInvolved class.

```
    public class ResearcherInvolved
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; } // Why virtual I do not know I am not hte author of this class
    }
```

```
    public class User
    {
// some other properties...
                public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Person
    {
// some other properties...
                public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

My Automapper Mapping profile

```
// my Automapper
 CreateMap<ResearcherInvolved, ResearcherInvolvedDto>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Person.Name)) //returns null instead of name
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.User.Person.Surname)); // returns null instead of surname
```

```
public class ResearcherInvolvedDto {
    public string Name {get; set}
    public string Surname{get; set}
}
```

I tried to add .Include(). To include populate Person property of User object but it throws null.
Also tried using .AfterMap() but there dst object of type ResearcherInvolved have values for User property. But User object property Person is null.

Expecting that after mapping property of Name and Surname in ResearcherInvolvedDto values are populated not just null.

Comment: Sounds like you have issue not with automapper, but with entity framework, you need to include additional properties before you map

Comment: If this is really about EF or also about EF please add the appropriate Tag.

Comment: you are dealing with Navigation properties... you are probably using 1 EF class for everything.. which would mean you'd need to fully load everytime.. if your operation is not able to fully load then your MVC needs to use a classes that are loaded with only what is needed.  EF classes usually are only ever fully loaded when loading 1 record.. not a good idea to fully load for searches

Comment: Use `ProjectTo` it will work without Includes. But I'm especially do not see benefits of using automapper for every move. Just write `Select` for concrete endpoint method.